# JGit branch checkout Issue

Tags: java, api, github, jgit

I am checking out a repository from github using the following code .

```
private String url = "https://github.com/organization/project.git";
    Git repo = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(url).setDirectory(directory).setCloneAllBranches(true).call();
    for (Ref b : repo.branchList().call()) {
        System.out.println("(standard): cloned branch " + b.getName());
    }
```

i am using the code

```
Git git = Git.open(checkout); //checkout is the folder with .git
git.pull().call(); //succeeds
```

If i chekout a branch

```
Git git = Git.open(new File(checkout)); //checkout is the folder with .git
System.out.println(git.getRepository().getFullBranch());
CheckoutCommand checkout = git.checkout();
Ref call = checkout.setName("kalees").call();
```

It throws org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref kalees can not be resolved.

What is the issue here, if i specify **"master"** instead of **"kalees"**, **it works fine**. what change should i do to checkout a specific branch?

**if i use the code**

```
git.checkout().setCreateBranch(true).setName("refs/remotes/origin/kalees");
```

It checkout the **kalees** branch. but when **i do pull operation**

```
git.pull().call();
```

it throws **org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.DetachedHeadException: HEAD is detached**. What could be the , whether this is a checkout issue or pull issue ?

Answer (score 5):

It should only happen if:

- `kalees` isn't an existing branch (or is incorrectly written, bad case)
- `kalees` is a remote branch you haven tracked yet a a local branch

If so you might need to create it first (a bit like in [this example](http://pastie.textmate.org/pastes/3580163))

```
git.branchCreate().setForce(true).setName("kalees").setStartPoint("origin/kalees").call();
```

Following "[JGit: Cannot find a tutorial or simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861881/jgit-cannot-find-a-tutorial-or-simple-example)", I would rather use:

```
git.branchCreate() 
       .setName("kalees")
       .setUpstreamMode(SetupUpstreamMode.SET_UPSTREAM)
       .setStartPoint("origin/kalees")
       .setForce(true)
       .call();
```

Comment: @kaleeswaran14 not sure. Maybe the `.setForce(true)` is important here?

Comment: @kaleeswaran14 I have edited the answer to include a more precise example.

Comment: @kaleeswaran14 You can checkout a remote branch, provided you create a local one based on that checkout (otherwise you are in a DETACHED HEAD mode, which is your case here).

Answer (score 2):

I met this question when I want to create a branch with an empty repository, there is no commit in this repository.

It's resolved when I commit something to the repository. Hope it's helpful  for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Muthu your code is working you only need to add origin/branch like this to the branch call

```
Ref call = checkout.setName("origin/kalees").call();
```